# How to share constants across different Android Studio modules

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am building a library project in Android Studio using several modules that I have written.

My main module, ModuleA, has the following string declared in one of my classes:

> public static final String KEY_START = "com.example.appname.KEY_START";

I want to know if it is possible to reference the public static string in ModuleA from ModuleB so that I don't need to code the same string in each module.

Is it possible to get a reference to the string in ModuleA from ModuleB?

Comment: I suppose you would have to make ModuleB use ModuleA as a dependency. If you're using Gradle this shouldn't be too much of a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by "i don't have to code the same string in each module" ? If the variables are static final, you access them via ClassName.variableName every time you want to use them. Wouldn't that work or am i missing something?

```
if(ClassName.KEY_START.equals(someOtherString))
      // same key pressed, do something
```

Comment: ModuleA is a different package than ModuleB. I think that @Rocoty has the right idea (ModuleB must have a dependency on ModuleA), I just haven't had a chance to test it yet

Comment: i didn't understood it right then, i'm not sure but i think you can just import the file and will work. give it a try and update your question maybe